# Android studio menu items missing

Tags: android-studio

**Version** : Android studio 3.0

1. Today I found weird issue for missing *Android* option in *Project Explorer*

[image: Here]

2. **File>New>Import Project** is also missing.

[image]

P.S day before it was working fine as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this step:

**Android Studio -> Settings -> Plugins -> "Android Support".**

enable this plugin..

Comment: Worked like a charm. I wonder how that plugin was disabled automatically.